# Ajax File Manager based on jQuery + NodeJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, file-management

I'm thinking of using the free ElFinder, based on jQuery/PHP, for my app. However, my backend is currently running NodeJS. And I'm lacking of resource to convert the backend part of ElFinder to NodeJS.

Is there any open source jQuery/NodeJS based Ajax File Manager out there?

Comment: I don't know if you already found your answer, but but I think this is what you're looking for: https://github.com/Studio-42/elFinder/wiki/Build-and-compress-elfinder-from-source

Comment: @I3B13: Thanks I actually found and used this elFinder.